# sklearn CountVectorizer returning all zeros - string conversion issue?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I am trying to use sklearn's CountVectorizer with a given vocabulary. My vocabulary is:

```
['humanitarian crisis', 'vacations for the anti-cruise crowd', 'school textbook', "b'cruise vacations for the anti-cruise", 'budget deal', "b'public school", 'u.n. announces', 'wrong petrol', 'vacations for the anti-cruise', "b'cruise vacations for the anti-cruise crowd"]
```

The input to vectorize on is taken from a pandas dataframe. I read this in from a csv with `pd.read_csv` and `encoding='utf8'`:

```
29371            b'9 quirky and brilliant paris boutiques'
20525    b'public school textbook filled with muslim bi...
2871     b'congress focuses on averting shutdown, but t...
29902    b'yarmouk siege: u.n. announces trip to syria ...
45596    b'fracking protesters arrested for gluing them...
6266         b'cruise vacations for the anti-cruise crowd'
```

After a call to `CountVectorizer(vocabulary=vocabulary).fit_transform()`, I get a matrix of all zeros:

```
(<6x10 sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 0 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>, <class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>)
```

Is this a problem because of the string types, or a problem with how I'm calling CountVectorizer? I'm not sure how else to convert the string types; I've tried multiple different calls to `encode` and `decode` in python2.7 and pandas. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: if you dump the iris dataset into a csv and then use your code on to read-in and fit-transform the species column, do you get the same error?

Comment: Show the full code. What's `vocabulary`? How are you passing the data into the `fit_transform()`

Comment: Vocabulary is the individual words learned by the `CountVectorizer` or what you want to use when the input docs are split by space (' '). So I am afraid, your vocabulary (which contains phrases and not words) will not match any words in the given data and hence the result is 0 elements. Read on about how the vocabulary works.

Answer (score 2):

Use "ngram_range = (min_word_count, max_word_count)" when you call CountVectorizer.

Comment: Can you add explanation about how you calculate min_word_count, max_word_count

Comment: In my case I was using `CountVectorizer` after `TfidfVectorizer` to save the count matrix for future use (to be used with `TfidfTransformer`). So have same `ngram_range` in both `CountVectorizer` and `TfidfVectorizer`. I had different `ngram_range` hence `CountVectorizer` resulted in all zeros.